# How can I remove a mainline kernel and move back to a supported kernel?

Tags: boot, kernel

I recently upgraded to kernel 3.4 in my Ubuntu 12.04. After that the computer is not booting up. So I used a previous kernel to boot up. Actually I don't want 3.4 kernel. So how can I remove it and use the previous one itself?

Answer (score 8):

How did you install it? If you just grabbed a load of deb files and installed them, getting rid of it is as simple as just finding the packages and running `apt-get remove` for each of them.

I've just had a cup of coffee so you get to bare the full brunt of my bashfu this morning... This should tell you what kernels are installed:

```
dpkg -l | awk '/linux-[^ ]+-[0-9]/ {print $2}'
```

Go through those and note the versions you want to nuke. Take care to also note your current install (uname -a) or any new kernels you have installed since booting. You don't want to remove the newest ones.

Anyway when you've got an idea, you can bulk-remove them by adapting this command:

```
sudo apt-get purge linux-{headers,image,image-extra}-3.5.0-{7,8,9}.*
```

The words and numbers in the braces will be expanded at runtime so the packages this will actually target are:

```
linux-headers-3.5.0-7*
linux-headers-3.5.0-8*
linux-headers-3.5.0-9*
linux-image-3.5.0-7*
linux-image-3.5.0-8*
linux-image-3.5.0-9*
linux-image-extra-3.5.0-7*
linux-image-extra-3.5.0-8*
linux-image-extra-3.5.0-9*
```

You can mess around with this but for cleaning up I find this much safer than a wide-wildcard (as I currently on a 3.5.* kernel).

Either way, ***read what apt-get is going to do*** before you say yes. Removing current kernels and all kernels is a surprisingly common predicament that Ubuntu users find themselves in. It's not unfixable but yeah, don't do it!

Be especially careful with wildcards and apt-get. If you don't believe me run `apt-get -s remove linux-image-3.4*` and see what it selects (yeah - *all* the kernels). Don't worry that command is in "simulate mode" so it won't do anything (and so doesn't need root).

Comment: Nearly four years later, your warnings remain true.  I was just a lazy -y away from... a headache day, when I read the confirmation a bit more closely than I normally would.  What a close call!

Comment: You can recover from it, it's just a pain in the bottom when you're not expecting it.

Answer (score 7):

> ### Uninstalling Mainline Kernels
>
> The mainline kernels have their own ABI namespace so they install side
>   by side with the stock Ubuntu kernels (each kernel has a separate
>   directory under `/lib/modules/VERSION` for example). This means that you
>   can keep several mainline and Ubuntu stock kernels installed at the
>   same time and select the one you need from the GRUB boot menu.
>
> If you would like to uninstall a mainline kernel anyway, first use:
>
> ```
> dpkg -l | grep "linux\-[a-z]*\-"
> ```
>
> to find the exact name of the kernel packages you want to uninstall,
>   and then do:
>
> ```
> sudo apt-get remove KERNEL_PACKAGES_TO_REMOVE
> ```
>
> Remember that several packages belong to one kernel version: common
>   headers, architecture specific headers and the architecture specific
>   image.

**Source:** https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/MainlineBuilds#Uninstalling_Mainline_Kernels